# MySQL Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '0' for key 'nombre_UNIQUE'

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a SQL query to insert and update rows from one table to another, the tables are `tmpTest` and `test` respectively. Some of the columns on `test` are set as UNIQUE, so when one of the incoming rows from `tmpTest` has the same value on that column it should update instead of insert.

My query:

```
INSERT INTO `test` ( name,lastName,age ) 
SELECT tmp.name,tmp.lastName,tmp.age FROM `tmpTest` tmp 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE test.name = tmp.name AND test.lastName = tmp.lastName AND test.age = tmp.age ;
```

Where `name` is the 'UNIQUE' column.

Case 1:

```
`tmpTest`:
name   lastName  age
Dulcie Sheree    43
Elvin  Wes       21

`test`:
id name    lastName  age
1  Dulcie  Lilibeth  34
2  Sophia  Dora      67
4  Jillian Britton   21

resulting `test`:
id name    lastName  age
1  0       Lilibeth  34
2  Sophia  Dora      67
4  Jillian Britton   21
10 Elvin   Wes       21
```

First row didn't update and changed the name field with a '0'. Second row inserted.

Case 2:

```
`tmpTest`:
name   lastName  age
Dulcie Sheree    43
Elvin  Wes       21

`test`:
id name    lastName  age
1  Dulcie  Lilibeth  34
2  Sophia  Dora      67
4  Jillian Britton   21
10 Elvin   Wes       21
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '0' for key 'name_UNIQUE'
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the series of ANDs in your UPDATE statement, these should be commas ','

I'd guess that MySQL is evaluating the expression

```
'Dulcie' = 'Dulcie' AND 'Sheree' = 'Lilibeth' AND 43 = 34
```

and getting 0 when any one of those values doesn't match its pair.

e.g.

```
mysql> SELECT 'Dulcie' = 'Dulcie' AND 'Sheree' = 'Lilibeth' AND 43 = 34;
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 'Dulcie' = 'Dulcie' AND 'Sheree' = 'Lilibeth' AND 43 = 34 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                         0 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm "guessing" here because I get

```
"Error Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Dulcie'"
```

when I try to run your code, so I can't duplicate your results.

When you run it again, you will already have 0 as a value and that will cause the UNIQUE constraint on `test` to fail.

Replace the ANDs with commas and you'll get the result you are after

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26d8d2/1